# How to smooth a plot of defined function in R?

Tags: r

For example, I want to plot this function `y1 = function(x) 2*x/sqrt(x^2 + 1)` in range (-2, 12)

But I tried using `plot(y1(-2:12), type='l')`, the plot comes out like a graph made up from several straight lines. How could I make it smoother?

Also, how could I define my own range of x and y shown on the plot? Thanks!
(sorry I can't insert any pictures of my plot because lacking reputation points...)

Comment: Try `y1(seq(-2,12,0.1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `curve` function:

```
curve(2*x/sqrt(x^2 + 1), -2, 12)
```

[image: Curve example]